# need to get Tasks where task tags is in $TagArray

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi Everyone I need to get Task where all task tags name is in `$TagArray`. I tried with my code but it returns Tasks when any task tags are in `$TagArray`.

My Code

```
$Tasks = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
    $q->with(['Tasks'=>function($q) use ($TagArray) { 
        $q->has('tasktags', '>' , 1)->whereHas('tasktags', function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
            $query->whereIn('name',$TagArray);
        })->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])->first();
```

this query check `Task->Tags` names in `$TagArray` but the problem is that it returning tasks when one of Task->Tags(tasktags) name is in $TagArray
i need to return Task just When All `Task->Tags` (tasktags) names is in `$tasktags`.

```
$query->whereIn('name',$TagArray);
```

Comment: Can you post your ERD?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Its hard to understand the relationships. Can you post the Models or the database design.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Z6RoA4m.png

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better for you to use Has Many Through.

```
 public function tags()
 {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Path', 'PathTag', 'pathtag_id', 'tag_id');
 }
```

You want to get tags of a given Path for this relation, so:

```
$path= Path::first();
$path->load(['tags' => function ($q)  use ($TagArray)  {
  $q->whereIn('name',$TagArray);
}]);


$path->tags;
```

Comment: Class 'PathTag' not found

Comment: No, I need To check if all tasktags name is in %TagArray

Comment: i tried          $posts2 = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
    $q->with(['Tasks'=>function($q) use ($TagArray) { 
        $q->has('tasktags', '>' , 1)->whereHas('tasktags', function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
            foreach($TagArray as $tag){
                $query->where('name',$TagArray);
            }
        })->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])->first();   but did't work